# Why do my images become unaligned when using an Anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I just can't figure this out. I've managed to align three images horizontally so they sit comfortably next to each other on the webpage. They are all sized accordingly to my needs too. However, I'm trying to use the Lightbox script with them (allows you to view the images in a pop out window) and to do that the image tag needs to be wrapped within an `<a>` tag to link to the Lightbox script. However, when I add the `<a>` tags the images become completely misaligned and disproportionate. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="imagecont">
    <a href="images/gallery/tube1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery0" data-title="24-Hour Tube concept art.">
        <img class="imagecenter" src="images/gallery/tube1.jpg" alt="Tube 1" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"/>
    </a>
    <a href="images/gallery/tube2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery0" data-title="24-Hour Tube concept art.">
        <img class="imagecenter" src="images/gallery/tube2.jpg" alt="Tube 2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
    </a>
    <a href="images/gallery/tube3.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery0" data-title="24-Hour Tube concept art.">
        <img class="imagecenter" src="images/gallery/tube3.jpg" alt="Tube 3" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"/>
    </a>
</div>

.imagecenter {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}

.imagecont {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use CSS on the anchor tag.

```
img a { adjust spacing as needed }
```

or make it a special class for those elements.

```
img a.anchorimage { adjust spacing as needed }
```

or better yet, use a reset stylesheet to start with before doing any of your own styling.

http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap the images in `a` tags, the `a` tags now become the flex-items which the images were before (i.e. the children of the `.imagecont` div which is the flex container), and the images become children of the `a` tags. So you have to apply the desired sizes, alignment etc. to the `a` tags  and make the images relative to the `a` tags, for example `heigth: 100%`.